# WInston Logging Req,Res

Tags: node.js, express, aws-sdk, winston

I have developed an express api app.

- implemented logging using winston.
- right now, I am logging to project directory
- deployed the app to render.com for free
- no feature to
  create the log files in render

Is there any other free hosting service with this feature?
If not how do I log this winston logger to cloud services?

I got this code from chatgpt but it is creating logs folder in project directory:

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import express from 'express';
import { createLogger, format, transports } from 'winston';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import fs from 'fs';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Configure AWS SDK
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

// Create a logs directory if it doesn't exist
const LOG_DIR = './logs';
if (!fs.existsSync(LOG_DIR)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(LOG_DIR);
}

// Create separate loggers for errors and access logs
const errorLogger = createLogger({
  level: 'error',
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }),
    format.printf(({ timestamp, level, message }) => {
      return `[${timestamp}] ${level}: ${message}`;
    })
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(), // Log errors to console
    new transports.File({ filename: './logs/error.log' }), // Log errors to error.log file
  ],
});

const accessLogger = createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }),
    format.printf(({ timestamp, level, message }) => {
      return `[${timestamp}] ${level}: ${message}`;
    })
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(), // Log access logs to console
    new transports.File({ filename: './logs/access.log' }), // Log access logs to access.log file
  ],
});

// Custom Winston transport to log to S3
const s3Transport = new transports.File({
  filename: './logs/access.log', // Change the file path as needed
});

// Add S3 transport to loggers
errorLogger.add(s3Transport);
accessLogger.add(s3Transport);

// Middleware for logging requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  accessLogger.info(`[${req.method}] ${req.url}`);
  next();
});

// Sample route with an intentional error
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  errorLogger.error('This is an intentional error');
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello, World!' });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: render.com has [log streams](https://render.com/docs/log-streams) that you could check out- they appear to be free and will get your data out of render. Where you put the logs is the next challenge. From render's docs as well, [BetterStack](https://betterstack.com/logs/pricing) has a respectable free tier too.

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested but the logs are not detailed.
For a GET request I can see only GET /